# isoHunt JSON search API for torrents not working

Tags: jquery, json, api, parsing, search

I am trying to use the isoHunt search API, but when I try to parse the URL (which seems to be correct after viewing its location in my broswer) nothing happens.  Below is the script I was using to try and test the script.  Does anyone know what could be causing this not to parse through the JSON file?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>isoHunt Search</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#button").click(function(){
    var keywords = $("#keywords").val();
    var url = "http://isohunt.com/js/json.php?ihq=" + keywords;
    $("#output").append(url);
    $.getJSON(url, function(data){
        $("#output").append("TEST123");
    });
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" name="keywords" id="keywords" />
<button id="button">Search</button>
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) is not your friend today.

Comment: Is there any way to make this work, or is the general idea of what I'm trying to do not possible due to the Same Origin Policy?

Comment: You might be able to use [YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/), if isohunt does not support [JSONP](http://json-p.org/).

Comment: An annoying thing here is that Isohunt returns the JSON response with contentType `text/plain;charset=utf-8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason ([read here](http://isohunt.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=150656&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=15&sid=)) isohunt doesn't support JSONP, so you cannot use use ajax cross domain here. But you can make your proxy instead, inside your domain